# Will star schema benefit in redshift?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

I'm new to redshift and I have a basic question on redshift's compatibility with star schema.

In general , will star schema benefit in redshift ?

Specific question ,

"KEY" distribution method in redshift supports distribution based on just one key , will it help in case of star schema where the fact table's key is combination of foreign keys.

Thanks
Sridhar

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Redshift works very well with star schemas, but you must do some optimizations.  See their whitepaper, http://aws.amazon.com/articles/8341516668711341, for some good guidelines.